# how to reduce quartz scheduling latency

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Im using Quartz under Spring backed by a jdbc job store, and im trying to make it trigger a job "now":

```
Trigger adHocTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(adHocTriggerKey).forJob(jobKey).startNow().build();
quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(adHocTrigger); //now
```

the measured latency between this call and the time the job actually starts executing is ~30 seconds by default. here's an example job to measure one-off trigger latency that i used:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
   Trigger trigger = context.getTrigger();
   if (!trigger.mayFireAgain()) {
      //its a one-off, compute latency
      long latency = System.currentTimeMillis() - trigger.getFinalFireTime().getTime();
      logger.info("firing latency is {} millis",latency);
   }
}
```

after reading [the documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigMain) i found the reason for the latency is the "org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime" configuration parameter (basically the job store polling frequency?), which can be configured as low as 1000 millis (at which point the latency im getting is on the order of 900 millis).

I understand that setting it this low may cause db thrashing (im using a jdbc job store) and is therefore not recommended, but is there any way to achieve low latency without resorting to this?

is there no optional configuration property that will cause "fire now" to actually do?

Comment: Why not just calling the job instead delegating on Quartz?

Comment: @PabloLozano - because it might be a long job and the code triggering it is ui-backed and cannot delay. also because the job is a singleton job (@DisallowConcurrentExecution) triggered by multiple triggers, some repeating, and i dont want to implement locking myself

Comment: @radai - have you got any solution ?

Comment: @VijayGupta - no. i've had to live with it

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this without lowering idleWaitTime is to modify QuartzScheduler slightly to support transactions. I don't use Spring, so I don't know what that would look like there, but this is the basic idea.

```
class TransactionAwareScheduler extends QuartzScheduler {
    @Override
    protected void notifySchedulerThread(long candidateNewNextFireTime) {
        if (insideTransaction) {
            transaction.addCommitHook(() -> {
                super.notifySchedulerThread(candidateNewNextFireTime);
            });
        }
    } else {
        super.notifySchedulerThread(candidateNewNextFireTime);
    }
}
```

It resolved the issue completely for us.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says 'triggerJob' will fire the job immediately. Check whether this satisfies your requirement.

```
 quartzScheduler.triggerJob(jobKey);
```

Comment: i've tried this. it gets me the exact same results as what i've described above. "immediately" actually means "next time the scheduler polls for work"